# Why/How does .Net allow me to negate a Nullable<T> that's null?

Tags: .net, nullable

I found myself staring at code that looks similar to this:

```
private double? _foo;

public double? Foo
{
    get { return _foo; }
    set { Baz(-value); }
}

public void Baz(double? value)
{
    // Perform stuff with value, including null checks
}
```

And in a test, I had this:

```
[Test]
public void Foo_test()
{
    ...
    Foo = null;
    ...
}
```

I anticipated that the test would fail (throw), since I thought that you really can't apply unary minus to `null`, which I believed would happen in `Foo`s setter. However, the unexpected happened and *the test did **not** fail*.

I could probably make an informed guess as to why this happens, but I figured that it'd be better if someone who actually knows what's going on could enlighten me.

*(And before someone points out the obvious: Yes, the negation should definitely be pushed down into the innards of `Baz`.)*

**Edit and follow up**

So, I'm grateful for the inputs from Jon Skeet and JaredPar, who both answered the *How* part of my question. After some googleing I found [this blog post by Eric Lippert explaining the mathematical definition of 'lifted'](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/06/27/what-exactly-does-lifted-mean.aspx), which makes perfect sense. I also read the relevant parts of the language specification, which are fairly straightforward explaining the mechanics of lifting in c#.

Specifically I now know that early in the process of lifting, a null check is made on the operand, and if the operand is null, null will be the result of applying the operator (unary minus, in my case). So `-null` is `null`.

*Now, to the "Why" part of the question.* If I define my own (unary) `operator -` on a `class` (in which I negate a wrapped value), and invoke this operator on a null reference, I will get a `NullReferenceException`. **Why is it, that 'lifting' behaves differently?** I'm actually interested in the reasoning behind this design decision. *I'm definitely **not** opposing the decision.*

Comment: The negation should definitely be pushed down into the... uhh.. Oh. Nevermind. :-P

Comment: I updated the question with a second part - the *"Why"*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why is it, that 'lifting' behaves differently? I'm actually interested in the reasoning behind this design decision.

Well, first off, you shouldn't always get a null reference exception. An operator call is statically dispatched; it doesn't need to do a null check. This is perfectly legal:

```
class P
{
  public static P operator -(P p)
  { return p; }

  static void Main()
  {
    P p1 = null;
    P p2 = -p1;
    Console.WriteLine(p2 == null);
  }
}
```

Really I think what your question means is "why do nullable value types get *automatic* lifting from non-nullable operations to nullable operations, but reference types require you to write specific logic in the operator if you want nullable semantics?"

It's a bit of a mess.

The thing is, reference types were *always* nullable to begin with, so you could always write that code yourself. Since nullable value types were added later, we added a mechanism so that all the existing non-nullable operators would suddenly work correctly with nullable types, so that you would not have to write all that boring code yourself.

There is a more general problem though. The more general problem is that we've conflated "null" to mean two different things. In the reference type world, null means "I do not refer to any object". In the value type world, null means what it means in databases: this quantity might have a value but we don't know what it is. What are the sales figures for November, if all the sales staff have not reported their results yet? There definitely is a dollar value to that quantity, but we don't know what it is, so we mark it as null.

Lifted arithmetic is designed to work on the "database null" semantics; null plus twelve is null. Something you don't know plus twelve is something else you don't know. Unfortunately, since we did not add nullable arithmetic to C# until version 2, there was already all the gear in place to treat null as the "there's an object reference that refers to no object" semantics.

Had we designed the whole thing from scratch, my suspicion is that (1) there would be nullable reference types, non nullable reference types, nullable value types and non nullable value types, and (2) there would be either a more clearly defined difference between null reference and null value, or their semantics would be more aligned when it comes to arithmetic, and (3) there would be automatic lifting of all non-nullable operations to nullable operations.

Note that [VB/VBScript implement the more clear distinction by having two separate values: Null, which is database null, and Nothing, which is reference null](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/30/53120.aspx).

Comment: Great stuff, exactly what I was looking/hoping for.

Answer (score 9):

It can negate it because that's how the "lifted" unary operators are defined... if you perform any operation such as negation, addition, subtraction etc and either operand is null, the result is null too.

For more details, see section 7.3.7 of the language specification.

In this particular case:

> For the unary operators (+, ++, -, --, !, ~) a lifted form of an operator exists if the operand and result types are both non-nullable value types. The lifted form is constructed by adding a single ? modifier to the operand and result types. The lifted operator produces a null value if the operand is null. Otherwise, the lifted operator unwraps the operand, applies the underlying operator, and wraps the result.

Note that this is specific to the language you're using - in particular, the & and | operators work differently with `bool?` values in C# than they do in VB.

Answer (score 4):

This is just a feature of nullable values in C#.  Applying the set of predefined unary and binary operators to a nullable value will produce `null` if any of the nullable inputs are `null`.

More information here in the Operators section

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx

**EDIT**

As Jon pointed out this rule does not hold for operators like `||`, `true` which have a non-nullable return type.

Comment: ... except things like `null | true` which gives "true" in C#, but Nothing in VB IIRC :)

Comment: @John thanks, updated.  Truthfully I just avoid boolean logic operators and nullable values.  I find the rules to be very unintuitive and prefer use explicit .HasValue to avoid getting them wrong.

Comment: ...or `GetValueOrDefault()` - a method on `Nullable<>` which seems to be used rarely but which comes in very handy to avoid the lifted operators.

Answer (score 0):

Write this expression in the debug watch or in the immediate window:

```
-((int?)null)
```

The result is still `null`, so evidently it's allowed.

Comment: It's quite evident that it's allowed from the fact that the OP's code compiles and runs without errors. He's looking for an explanation as to *why* this happens.

Comment: While this works correctly in this scenario, be wary of using the immediate window in general to verify corner case coding scenarios.  The immediate window is much closer to an interpreter than an actual evaluation.  It will deviate from the actual language on occasion.

Comment: This is like saying it works because it works. (but I will be nice and not give you a -1)

Comment: @JaredPar - Interesting, any examples?

Comment: @Reinderien, couple that come to mind. 1) `base` doesn't work and will evaluate just like `this`.  2) calling a virtual method on a struct will always box when it should not (can produce visible differences when mutations are involved)

Comment: (3) expressions involving lambdas, including query comprehensions, are not allowed, (4) expressions are evaluated without consideration of accessibility rules.